# Is it possible to pass parameters/prefill filters to the add product module in lightning

Tags: lightning

In classic you could use URL hacks to pass filter parameters to the add product/production selection. In lightning you have a module with filters and i'm wondering if there's a way of creating a button to prefil/select some of those filters?

So far no google-fu has answered the question, and i'm looking at just developing my own add product to override the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it's not, you have to do it custom.